# Getting an default namespace for nested XML element by (LINQ to XML)

Tags: c#, xml, linq

> Im trying to get default namespace for nested element. Part of my XML file is:

```
<Node xmlns="http://namespace-root/">
 <Node1>
  <Node2 xmlns="http://namespace-element">Value</Node2>
 </Node1>
</Node>
```

> Part of my query code is 
>   (namespaces 'namespaceNode' and 'namespaceElement' are XNamespace objects:

```
    from node in xDoc.Elements(namespaceNode+ "Node")
    select new DataObject
    {
        Xmlns = node.Element(namespaceNode+ "Node1").Element(namespaceElement+ "Node2").GetDefaultNamespace(),
        Value = (string)node.Element(namespaceNode+ "Node1").Element(namespaceElement+ "Node2")
    }
```

> Value property gets the value of the element, but how can I read the namespace of this node to Xmlns property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I normally do it

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement node = doc.Root;
            XNamespace xNs = node.GetDefaultNamespace();

            XElement node2 = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Node2").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace x2Ns = node2.GetDefaultNamespace();
```

Comment: I tried it (XNamespace x2Ns = node2.GetDefaultNamespace()) but I got a namespace with field "NamespaceName" empty. When I do node2.Name.Namespace I got Xnamespace element with NamespaceName filed with value. What is the reason?

Comment: The first node I assumed the namespace was in the root node. I wasn't sure and just wanted to give an example of getting the namespace from the root and another example of getting the namespace from a node that wasn't the root.

Comment: Yes, the first namespace was in the root node. I'm just curious why .Name.Namespace returns something different than .GetDefaultNamespace() for this element. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Simple.  .Name.Namespace is the prefix of the tag and the tag does not have a prefix